# What are the cut/fold vectors that you send to a die cutter called?

Tags: print-design, dieline, diecut

I want to call them "dielines" because they are for a die but I know that means something else to designers.  I don't want to call them "cut lines" because they may also include score or perforation paths. I am currently working on an app that generates SVG designs for cutter/plotters or laser cutters and am having a hard time with naming.

Comment: ...ermm.. dielines. What else do you think it means?

Comment: @scott - perhaps the OP is confusing it with the homophone"dyelines" which were prints made using a kind of contact printing technology for making copies of line drawings/plans?  These were sometimes also referred to as "blueprints" or "diazo prints".

Comment: Hmm, I heard it could refer to those little L marks on the corners of a print but now that I do more research it seems like that's the right term, whoops, thanks for confirming @scott

Comment: @J.Barca those little L shaped marks are called "crop marks".  They're used for trimming a print job with a guillotine.

Comment: @BillyKerr, fun fact: 1977 was the last year a person was guillotined in France.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, they're called die lines!